# Looping through data table to get value

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable with multiple rows. I'm using a foreach loop to loop through each item and return the name. This is returning the same (1st) value for each row. What have I done wrong?

```
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("tag", typeof(string));
            string name = hfSelected.Value;
            string[] names = name.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                table.Rows.Add(new object[] { names[i] });                  
            DataRow row = table.Rows[0];

            foreach (var item in table.Rows)
            {

                Value = row["tag"].ToString() // this is returning the same value for both items in the table.

            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return the name" ? What is "Value" - variable?

Comment: I mean return the value of "tag". The value of hfSelected.Value is oranges,apples. I'm trying to return oranges and then apples.

Comment: As answer says, you should change row["tag"] to item["tag"]. But i'm afraid that is not enough, as you have to plan proper logic what to do inside loop..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a comment you mentioned that you get the error:

> cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object

when trying to access `item["tag"]` in the foreach loop.

You need to explicitly declare the `DataRow` in the foreach.

```
// declare DataRow here, not var 
foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)
{
    // use item here
    Value = item["tag"].ToString();    // use += to concatenate string
}
```

The reason is that the `DataRowCollection` implements a non-generic `IEnumerable` so you index an `object` instead of `DataRow`.  The solution above casts to a `DataRow`.

I would recommend looking at the `Field<T>()` and `AsEnumerable()` methods from `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.  [AsEnumerable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.  [Field()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=netframework-4.7.2) provides strongly typed access to the values (ie it casts/converts the types for you).

Then you can do:

```
foreach (var item in table.AsEnumerable())
{
    // item is a DataRow here
    var myString = item.Field<string>("tag");     // gets string

    // you can also do
    var myInt = item.Field<int>("Id");            // gets int
    var myDate = item.Field<DateTime?>("Date");   // gets nullable DateTime?
    var myValue = item.Field<decimal>("Price");   // gets decimal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Carl is correct, this is producing the same output, because inside the iteration, you use the same row, all the time. You should use 'item', instead of 'row' there (you don't need 'row' at all).

The exception you receive is because you declared 'item' with a dynamic type, it's

```
 foreach (var item in table.Rows)
```

You can try

```
 foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)
```

this way, you'll be able to get the column info.

Comment: Using `var` does not make `item` dynamic.

Comment: No, I didn't mean it receives the type "dynamic", but that it's given a type dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

your iteration seems to be using the same 'row' variable instead of the 'item' variable you defined in the foreach statement.

Comment: If I use `item["tag"].ToString()` I get: cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object.